# AWS Cognito: How to assign the Group memberships to the user using amazon-cognito-identity-js?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I am using AWS-Cognito for authentication in the React.js application. I am using hosted UI of AWS-Cognito to get the **access_token** and **id_token**. I want to add selective Group memberships like "**cognito:manage_menu**" etc in AWS-Cognito when the user sign-up into the application using **'amazon-cognito-identity-js'**.

Kindly guide me. Thanks